# Searching for EUR exchange with high trading volume

Tags: exchanges, europe

I'm currently trading on kraken.com which works perfectly fine. Now I want to discover other EUR exchanges which have good reputation, a relatively high trading volume and preferably low trading fees.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I have used Bitstamp in the past and was satisfied, but fees start at 0.25%. Bitcurex has a flat 0.15% right now but I have never used them. If you trade relatively large trading volumes Kraken has very low fees.

Comment: @karask thanks for your comment. unfotunately bitstamp has now EUR trading.bitcurex has a huge gap between bid and ask. are they trustworthy?